# ASP.NET Masterpage and Context.RewritePath

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET Website, I am trying to use Server.Transfer to redirect client to different url(all pages resides in same domain) instead of using Response.Redirect because of performance issue and heavy flickering. But when I use Server.Transfer, all session values are wiped out and getting NullReference error even though if I enable page level EnableSessionState. After several attempt, i tried Context.ReWritepath just to change the url and lost all masterpage contents like menus, headers. Any idea? Any help? Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This technique is great for wizard-style input forms split over multiple pages. But there's another thing you'll want to watch out for when using the `preserveForm` parameter. ASP.NET has a bug whereby, in certain situations, an error will occur when attempting to transfer the form and query string values. You'll find this documented at

[Q316920](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?id=kb;en-us;Q316920)

The unofficial solution is to set the `enableViewStateMac` property to `True` on the page you'll be transferring to, then set it back to `False`. This records that you want a definitive `False` value for this property and resolves the bug.

[Read More here](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm)